# Image not loading on ionic serve due to path problem in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

When I am doing `ionic serve`, it loads `home.html`. I am calling image there. For some reason the images are kept at `xampp/htdocs/files/hydrocarbon_files/image001.gif`

In normal HTML it loads image perfectly fine but in Ionic project, image path is shown as

> http://localhost:8100/files/hydrocarbon_files/image001.gif

It does not show image from above url, because orignally the path is -

> http://localhost:8100/files/hydrocarbon_files/image001.gif

What should I do so that image loads locally as well?

Comment: ionic dont support external paths. you have to copy that image inside ionic projects's assets folder then it will work.

Comment: worked, please post this as an answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ionic dont support external paths. you have to copy that image inside ionic projects's assets folder then it will work.
E.G

```
<img src="assets/img/imageName.png" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Import and inject WebView and DomSanitizer.

```js
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {WebView} from '@ionic-native/ionic-webview/ngx';

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
            private webView: WebView) {}
```

Sanitize the URL of the image (you can do it in `ngOnInit`, for instance):

```js
const uri = 'xampp/htdocs/files/hydrocarbon_files/image001.gif';
this.imgSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.webView.convertFileSrc(uri));
```

Then use the sanitized source in your html:

```html
<img [src]="imgSrc">
```

Hope this helps.